# Navigation of a recorded file to media element or media player launcher

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I've created an audio recorder for wp7. In that i actually used a listbox(named as filesListBox) to show the recorded audio files and if the user click on any file, then it simply plays the audio(**Not by MediaPlayerLauncher**). It worked perfectly.

```
private void filesListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = (string)e.AddedItems[0];
        PlayFromIS(filename);
    }
```

After this, i have used the **MediaPlayerLauncher** to play the recorded audio files from the listbox. It actually opens the file but while playing the audio, its tempo is extremely becomes low and the voice changes to something.

```
private void filesListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string filename = (string)e.AddedItems[0];

            MediaPlayerLauncher mediaPlayerLauncher = new MediaPlayerLauncher();
            mediaPlayerLauncher.Media = new Uri(filename, UriKind.Relative);
            mediaPlayerLauncher.Controls = MediaPlaybackControls.All;
            mediaPlayerLauncher.Location = MediaLocationType.Data;
            mediaPlayerLauncher.Orientation = MediaPlayerOrientation.Landscape;
            mediaPlayerLauncher.Show();
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException x)
        {

        }
    }
```

Due to this i have then created a MediaElement.xaml page and added a **MediaElement** in it. But i dont know how to access the **filename(from MainPage.xaml)** in the MediaElement.xaml Page like the media player launcher does.

```
myMediaElement.Source = new Uri("??Don't know what to write here to access the filename??", UriKind.Relative);
```

I think **MediaPlayerLauncher** is much better than **MediaElement** but either one is accepted. Can anybody help me with this? Thanks in advance for your hard work!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the job, given that you can access the file from the Isolated Storage:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = file.OpenFile("file/path/here", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
              this.mediaElement.SetSource(stream);
    }
}
```